# HP P4515 printer in 10.7.4 - what driver?

Tags: macos, printing

HP's official support page lists the Laserjet P4515 as a compatible printer in 10.7 using the HP Print Software from Apple (per http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c01664444&lc=en&cc=us&dlc=en#N2473). However, the P4515 is not listed in my available printer software when installing a new printer.

Is there a different driver name I should be using which also matches the HP P4515 model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears HP supports this printer with the P4014 series drivers.  Try installing them manually and use the `Print and Scan` page in `System Preferences` to add the printer to your machine.

http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/ProductList.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&taskId=135&prodTypeId=18972&prodSeriesId=3558788